# ActiveRecord query returns an incorrect model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been scratching my head over this one for a little while, and though I'm sure its a stupid mistake, I've reached the point where I must consult SO if I am to preserve the hair follicles I have left.

I've written a function in Rails (3.1.2) which should return an array populated with ActiveRecord model objects (users, in this case) which meet a certain criterion.  The criterion is that the user's current list (denoted by the field active_list_id) must not be nil. The code follows:

```
def build_list_array
   @lists = Array.new
   User.all.each do |user|
     @active_list_id = user.active_list_id
     @lists<< List.find(@active_list_id) if @active_list_id != nil #TODO WHAT?!? WHY IS  THIS RETURNING USERS?
   end
end
```

As you can see, I'm initializing an empty array, cycling through all users and adding their active list to the array if the relevant reference on the user record is not nil. The problem is, this is returning user objects, not list objects.

Here are the associations from the user and list models:

```
user model:
  has_many :lists
  has_many :tasks

list model:
  belongs_to :user
```

A brief word about the reference to active_list: A user can have many lists, but only one is active at any time. Therefore, I need to reference that list on the user record. The active list is not a foreign key in the typical sense, then.

I appreciate any help you can give me...Thanks =)

Comment: I am not answering exactly to your question but IMO, the simplest approach would be: 1. Add a boolean field to your `lists` table with `default: false` 2. Add `has_one :active_list, conditions: where(active: true)` to your `User` model. 3. Add `scope :active, where(active: true)` to your `List` model. 4. Query `@lists = List.active`. In bonus you have very nice methods: `User.active_list`, `list.active?` etc.

Comment: 2. `has_one :active_list, class_name: 'List', conditions: ['active = ?', true] ` that's better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, your `build_list_array` will return an array of `User` because of the behavior of `each`.  When iterating over a collection using `each`, the call to `each` returns the original collection.

For example,

```
list = []
# returns => []
[1,2,3,4,5].each { |number| list << number * 10 }
# returns => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list
# returns => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

In your code, the last statement in your `build_list_array` method is the `each` call, meaning the return value of `each` is what is returned by the method.  If you simply added a return statement at the end of the method you would be good to go.

```
def build_list_array
  @lists = Array.new
  User.all.each do |user|
    @active_list_id = user.active_list_id
    @lists<< List.find(@active_list_id) if @active_list_id
  end
  return @lists  # Actually return @lists
end
```

That being said, you should probably use something like Bradley's answer as a basis for more "correct" Rails code.

Comment: Thank you, a very detailed explanation of the issue which was hidden in plain sight. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`each` always returns the collection it iterates on (no matter what happens inside the block). Sounds like you want to return `@lists` at the end of your method.

You seem to be making a curious use of instance variables. You could also fetch this in one query via a join, something along the lines of

```
List.joins('inner join users on active_list_id =lists.id')
```

Comment: 'Curious use of instance variables' is one way to put it, in fact I wrote that code back when I had little to no idea what I was doing (not that I have much of an idea now, clearly) and I never took those @'s off until today. Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

Activerecord's Arel is your friend here:

```
User.where(:active_list_id.not_eq => nil)
```

Comment: I think the not_eq method is provided by the metawhere gem or similar. `User.where(User.arel_table[:active_list_id].not_eq(nil))` is the best I can work out in pure arel.

Comment: This seems a very attractive way to do this, and I've been meaning to dig into Arel properly for a while. Doesn't one need to instantiate an arel object/table in order to do something like this, though?  Thank you for your help =)

Comment: To be fair, you wouldn't be doing this in a controller
`scope :with_active_list, where(arel_table[:active_list_id].not_eq(nil))` is slightly better but not really that pretty

Answer (score 1):

Extending Steven's answer, to get the Lists

```
class User
  belongs_to :active_list, :class_name => "List"

def build_list_array
  @lists = User.where('active_list_id is not null').map(&:active_list).compact
```